# How to extract all timesteps except the specified timesteps from a netcdf file using cdo

Tags: cdo-climate

We usually use 'cdo seltimestep' to select the days we want to extract from a netcdf file into an output file that includes only the days we specified.

```
cdo seltimestep,6,10,11 2000-03.nc 03-days.nc
```

but now we want to do the opposite, we want to select all the days except the ones specified. Is there a way to do that in `cdo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the operator `delete` in the following way:

```
cdo delete,timestep=6,10,11 ifile ofile
```

Comment: Yeah that does the job for me, Thanks Adrian!